# what is the c# rule about this inline assignment

Tags: c#

I was expecting the result to be 0

[dotnetfiddler demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/7Iyyoa)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int value = 5;
        value += (value += 5) > 5 ? -value : +value;

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

1. value start at 5
2. value increase to 10
3. the coalesce detect that it is higher than 5
4. it return -10

since value was detected to be higher than 5, which mean it had the value of 10 in this case, i was expecting  10 += -10

what is happening is 5 += -10

what define this behavior?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you think it would be 0?  After following the code through, I reached the conclusion of -5, which your fiddle then demonstrated.

Comment: I think `+=` grabs a temp copy of the value before running the expression that it adds to it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe value change to 10 so i was under the impression that all value would become 10

Comment: @JamesThorpe First is adds 5, so value is 10, then it selects -10 to add to the value, which the OP assumes is 10, thus the answer would seem to be 0.

Comment: @juharr Indeed - but I think this info should be in the question to make it complete.

Comment: Write never code like this if you want to keep a  good working relationship to your colleagues

Comment: @JamesThorpe i updated my question

Comment: @TimSchmelter i was trying to do http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65577/the-sum-is-always-15 when i got some weird result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets look at the emitted IL in Release Mode:

```
Program.Main:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    // Load 5
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // Store value
IL_0002:  ldloc.0     // Load value
IL_0003:  dup         // Create a duplicate of value (5)
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.5    // Load 5
IL_0005:  add         // Add 5 to variable. Now value == 10
IL_0006:  dup         // Duplicate value.
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // Store value (10)
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.5    // Load 5
IL_0009:  bgt.s       IL_000E // Check value (10) > 5. If true go to IL_000E
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // value
IL_000C:  br.s        IL_0010
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     // Load value (10)
IL_000F:  neg         // Negate value (-10)
IL_0010:  add         // -10 + 5 = -5
IL_0011:  stloc.0     // Store -5 in value
IL_0012:  ldloc.0     // value
IL_0013:  call        System.Console.WriteLine // Print value
IL_0018:  ret
```

This kind of code is confusing. Try avoiding it at all costs.

Comment: i was actually currently looking at the IL myself

Comment: Seeing this answer got accepted in between I stopped formulating my answer....Though the IL shows what's happening, I thought the questions was about the **rules** why. And I think what may have confused the OP is: `value += x` is expanded as `value = value + x` and the arguments of the `+` operator are evaluated left to right. So it is clear that at the end there is `value = 5 + (-10)`.

Comment: @RenéVogt It actually got expended to `int temp = value; value = temp + x`.

Comment: @RenéVogt, if you think your answer can add informations, go ahead, more is always better

Answer (score 9):

I believe it functions like so:

```
int value = 5;
value += //5 is stored here for the calculation
   (value += 5) // 5 is modified to 10
     > 5 
     ? -value //-10 
     : +value; //10
```

so you get `5 - 10 = -5`

Further reading: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: As commentary, you should never use `+=` like this. But I answered for academic purposes.